# Linear model for nested within subject design

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I want to find a suitable linear model for my analysis. I have a nested experiment design. There are 2 conditions, 40 subjects, and 20 measurements within a subject. The condition is a within subject fixed effect, every subject is tested in both conditions. **I want to fit a linear model to my data that allows me to address the significance of my fixed effect (condition)**. Here's a scheme of my design for easier interpretation.

```
condition   subject     measurement
###################################
cond1       sub1        meas1
                        meas2
                        meas3
                        ...
                        ###########
            sub2        meas1
                        meas2
                        meas3
                        ...
            ...
            #######################
cond2       sub1        meas1
                        meas2
                        meas3
                        ...
                        ###########
            sub2        meas1
                        meas2
                        meas3
                        ...
            ...
```

Since measurements are nested within each subject, I figured I'd be using random intercept linear mixed model where condition is a fixed effect and subject is a random effect. However, this would assume that the subject means are normally distributed. This is not the case in my design. I don't want my model to assume anything about the relations among subject means. Subjects are all over and I just want to address **the effect of the condition within subjects**.

Can someone suggest me a suitable model for my analysis that doesn't care about the distribution of my subject means? I was thinking of subtracting from each measurement the mean of the corresponding subject, and then running the two level linear mixed model I explained above. But I'm unsure whether this is the right way.

If someone can provide me with code for statsmodels or R, that's a bonus .

Comment: The model assumes that the residuals of the subject means (the random intercepts) are $N(0, \sigma_{u0}^2)$, not that the means themselves are normal. Why is this a problem? Have you looked at the $u_0$ residuals from a multilevel model with this data? If that doesn't work, you could use a Bayesian approach in which you give the parameters a different distribution (student's t perhaps)?

Comment: I truly appreciate your helpful response! I'd like to follow up with a question.
I understand that residuals of the subject means are assumed to follow (0,20), but does that not mean the the means themselves have to come from (γ00, 20), where γ00 is the grand mean of subject means? Does the model allow the subject means to be completely independent? In the latter case, I'd think γ01*Wj is the term in the model that allows this. Is this true? For sake of clarity, I'm getting these notations from this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model#Random_intercepts_model

Comment: *The random intercepts ($u_0$) are uncorrelated across subjects.* They represent subject differences in the outcome that are due to unmeasured personal characteristics of those subjects..

Comment: I think I'm on the right track of understanding the underlying concepts here. So does this mean that $\gamma_{01}$ is different and independent for each $j$ subject? And that $W_j$ has only two levels (0 or 1)? Again, using notations from that wiki page I linked above.

Comment: The coefficient on $\gamma_{01}$ quantifies the linear association between whatever $W_j$ measures and the outcome at the subject level. It is, more or less, a weighted average the correlation between $W_jj$ and the outcome after adjusting for other subject level covariates.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much! You were very helpful.